# Is there any equivalent to the HTML anchor tag on Nativescript?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I'm trying to display a simple image or text with a link such as an HTML `<a>` anchor tag

```
  <ListView [items]="items | async" (itemTap)="onItemTap($event)">
    <template let-item="item">
      <StackLayout>
        <Image [src]="item.imageUrl" ></Image> 
 <!--<Image [src]="item.imageUrl" href="http://google.com"></Image>-->
      </StackLayout>
    </template>
  </ListView>
```

It seems the only options is to be using onItemTap and getting the item url and manually setting the url content to be displayed on a separate webview. Are there any tags that would automatically open a separate browser page on the phone and display the URL content of the item?

Comment: Think you will have to make function and from that you can open browser with desired URL.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For your case, you could use `openUrl()` and on tap Event on some of the components to open the needed page. For example:

```
export function onTap(args:EventData){        
    openUrl("https://www.google.com");
}
```

You could also review the sample project [here](https://github.com/tsonevn/openUrlExample/).

Comment: +1, but I had to require utils module first `var utilsModule = require("tns-core-modules/utils/utils");` and the use `utilsModule.openUrl("https://www.google.com")`